# Row spacing of multi-line paragraph cell in `tabular` in the `res` document class

Tags: tables, document-classes, documentclass-writing

I was trying to compose my CV (as a mathematician) in LaTeX, and found the document class [res](http://ctan.org/pkg/res) on CTAN that appealed to me aesthetically. The cls file for this document class can be found here: http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/resume/res.cls.

However, there is a strange problem with the `tabular` environment in this class. The row spacing is insufficient when a paragraph cell has multiple lines. Consider the following example (using `res.cls` linked above):

```
\documentclass{res}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{4in}}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin a justo
  in lorem. \\
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin a justo
  in lorem. \\
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin a justo
  in lorem. \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The output I get is:

[image: output with <code>res.cls</code>]

As you can see, adjacent rows are too close—the letters "j" and "L" almost touched each other.

In comparison, below is what I get from `amsart` (replacing `res` with `amsart` in the above code snippet):

[image: output with <code>amsart</code>]

and below is what I get from `article`:

[image: output with <code>article</code>]

Both of these have much reasonable spacing.

**Since I know nothing about document class writing, could anyone help me look into `res.cls` and identify what's wrong with the spacing? And is it possible to somehow fix this issue in `res.cls`?** Thanks in advance.

---

I am fully aware that this question might be too localized to be constructive; however, I can't find other helpful sources to resolve this issue. Sure I might have an answer myself after reading the TeXbook or other multi-hundred-page TeX programming reference manuals, but this is not so realistic for a lay LaTeX user who focuses mainly on content (after all, content is what LaTeX emphasizes). I apologize for my potential abuse of this site.

By the way, **if you know any simple and elegant CV document class suitable for mathematicians (in academia), you are more than welcome to leave me a comment.** Thanks.

Comment: You might redefine \arraystretch in your preamble:  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}, for instance (you must load the array package).

Comment: @Bernard Thanks Bernard. \arraystretch almost solves the problem (is there any harmful side effect, btw? I know that a stretched struct is inserted into every row; does it have effects on other macros?) However, I'm a bit reluctant to use this workaround, because when the rows are stretched, line spacing inside a multi-line cell is also stretched; the spacing throughout the document is not uniform this way. (And in fact, the space between two rows is still a bit thinner than inside a cell, only less noticeable.)

Comment: As far as I know, line spacing is not affected by \arraystretch – unless I'm completely mistaken. A solution could be to change the value of \arraystretch to some greater value. Another solution would be to use \setlength{\extrarowheight}{n pt}, choosing n so that the inter-row spacing seems correct.

Comment: @Bernard Oops I'm super sorry about reporting the wrong problem—I temporarily confused myself. What I actually mean is that the vertical space between two single-line `p` cells is also stretched (notice that the original issue only occurs when the `p` cell spans multiple lines).

Comment: The `res` class is dated 1989; a revision for making it compatible with LaTeX2e has been made in 2001. There are far better classes for CVs.

Comment: @KevinSayHi: Is the solution with \extrarowheight more satisfactory? I'm not sure to understand very well the problem, as I do not know this class – personally, I use moderncv.

Comment: @egreg That's true. Actually I found `res` because it is recommended on the NYU Math graduate resources page. Would you recommend some better classes suitable for mathematicians, if I might ask? There are twenty something packages for CV on CTAN. I browsed through some, and they don't look as good as [this simple and elegant one composed with `res`](http://www.math.nyu.edu/student_resources/sample_cv.pdf) (if not for the nasty spacing issue); some of them are too plain, and some are too fancy—maybe better for professionals in the industries. Anyway, I don't know how configurable they are.

Comment: @KevinSayHi I'm no expert in CV classes. For the problem at hand, if you say ``\strut\\`` the spacing will be uniform.

Comment: @egreg Wow, indeed. Thanks for the help, I guess I will stick with this 1980s product then.

Comment: @Bernard Surprisingly, I revisited the solution, and found out that if I simply load the package `array` and do nothing, the spacing would be correct. Thanks for the help, and sorry for all the hassle.

Comment: @KevinSayHi would you like to answer this one to take it off the unanswered list? Self-answers are perfectly acceptable, and a good one may earn you additional reputation. :-)

Comment: @PaulGessler Sure, done that, although it's certainly not a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I've found a satisfactory answer, so what I did in the end was to manually stick `\vspace` when appropriate.

---

Or you could try `\usepackage{array}`, which does solve the problem for the minimal example, but might have other problems when things are more complicated.

Comment: I thought you said that `\usepackage{array}` fixed everything? That would have been a better self-answer than this one. :-)

Comment: @PaulGessler This is an old question and I can't remember the details. But I did briefly inspect my final source code (which hasn't been modified much in the past year) and found that I just used `\vspace` in the end. I guess that's because `\usepackage{array}` solves the problem for the MWE but could bring up other issues.